# Creating inventory database when product unit price change frequently

Tags: sql, database-design

I am working on this project that involve sales management. I have the schema below. I have a situation where unit price change frequently. I want to prevent product duplicate in the PRODUCT MASTER table.Also, there I will be finding monthly profit by subtracting unit price from sales price. Please I need assistance on how to update prices and make sure old unit price is associated with old products purchased and new unit price is associated with new products. Thanks.

[image: CLICK TO SEE MY SCHEMA]

Comment: It's probably better if you include your schema in text format, instead of an image. Also, even though you are using Access, your question is generally an SQL question; and it might be a good idea to setup your schema on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). Choose MSSQL Server 2017 from the dropdown, as Microsoft Access SQL is closest to SQL Server.

Comment: Also note that having spaces in your field and table names is generally a bad idea -- it means you have to surround these table and field names with square brackets in SQL, e.g. `[Receiving details].[Product ID]` in your queries, instead of `ReceivingDetails.ProductID` or `Receiving_details.Product_ID`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: nitpicking, in **T-SQL** you would need those dreaded square brackets. in "SQL" you would need double quotes for identifiers that contain illegal characters, e.g. `"Receiving Detail"` - but I do agree: stay away from identifiers that would require that

Comment: If you're only interested in profit, the simplest way is to save the unit price and sales price on the actual `Purchase Order Detail` record

Answer (score 2):

Offhand, I can think of two ways to do this:

**If old prices are important only to know the profit in a given time period**:

1. `Product master` should contains the current price
2. Add another field to `Purchase order details` for the unit price **at the time of the order**.
3. When you add a record to `Purchase order details`, copy the current price from `Produce master` to `Purchase order details`.
4. Update the price in `Product master` whenever you need to.

**If you want to track old prices, even if no items were ordered with that price**:

1. Remove the price fields from `Product master`
2. Add a new table, for price updates. This will have three fields:

   1. product ID
   2. date/time on which the price was changed
   3. the new price
3. When you want to calculate price for a given `Purchase order details`, look in this new table. Find the latest record that is earlier (has a smaller date/time for the price change) than the `[Purchase order].[order date]`.
4. When you want to update the price, add a record to this new table.